# Quering two tables without any relation

Tags: mysql, sql

suppose we have two tables `users` and `products`

table `users` has an accountBalance column

table `users` schema:

```
userId  accountBalance .........
1           500        .........
2           45000      .........
3           4238827    .........
.               .      .........
.               .      .........
.               .      .........
```

table `products` has a price column

table `products` schema:

```
productId   price      .........
1           40000      .........
2           55000      .........
3           90000      .........
.               .      .........
.               .      .........
.               .      .........
```

these table don't have any relation so i can't join them by a common key. What i want to know is to find out what products each user can buy and format it as the expected result following:

the `expected result` is:

```
userId  productIdsUserAffordToBuy
1       NUll
2       1*2
3       1*2*3
.       .
.       .
.       .
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to create a list inside a single column and joining against the condition `accountBalance >= price` you can in fact perform a `LEFT JOIN` (necessary to return `NULL` for the user who can't afford anything, rather than omitting the row):

```
SELECT
  userId,
  GROUP_CONCAT(productId) AS productIdUserAffordToBuy
FROM
  users
  LEFT JOIN products ON users.accountBalance >= products.price
GROUP BY userId
```

Comment: Thnaks Michael Works like a charm

Answer (score 5):

```
select userid,accountbalance,group_concat(productid) as productaffordtobuy
from users cross join products 
where price<=accountbalance
group by userid
```

[SQL FIDDLE HERE>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/57f51/7)

Comment: Does mysql support cross join's?

Comment: It does support cross join. However, i ommit to take care of what if the users can't afford anything. Thus, using left join is more appropriate in this case.

Comment: Should have asked a better question - is the cross join you provide supported by mysql - Last time I read the docs there was limited support - or maybe I am thinking of something else

Answer (score 1):

`Cross Join` without any relationship or `id` is bit tricky

```
select userid,accountbalance,productid as productaffordtobuy
from users 
cross join products 
where price<=accountbalance
group by userid
```